# Why have a filter before the LNA in LoRa boards?

Tags: rf, lora, snr, lna

I've looked through some Semtech reference board schematics and found one strange thing: they put SAW filters both before and after the LNA. For example here is part from a Semtech reference board electrical schematic ([1](https://www.semtech.com/products/wireless-rf/lora-core/sx1302cfdxxxgw1) and [2](https://www.semtech.com/products/wireless-rf/lora-core/sx1302cfd915gw1h).)

[image]

The same thing from the [SX1301](https://www.semtech.com/products/wireless-rf/lora-core/sx1301) datasheet:

[image]

Here is photo of RAK831 which uses the same scheme:

[image]

Its SNAILTEK copy:
[image]

The same thing in an IC880A gateway:

[image]

They also have filters before the LNA, which reduces SNR.  What can be a reason for that?

Comment: Seriously, who close-voted this as "use of electronic devices is off-topic"? Understanding a RF rx path of a posted schematic is clearly electrical engineering and definitely on-topic.

Comment: What does the data sheet for the SPF5043Z tell you?

Comment: @Lundin I voted to close this question for two good reasons. The two items are products and we are not privy to the design decisions made by the engineers that designed them. Nor does the question state the operating frequency and bandwidth requirements. Secondly, the SPF5043Z does not appear to have been investigated as it is likely that it is this part that requires the filtering in order to comply with whatever requirements were judged to be important by the original designers of those two products. I could have voted to close on lack of info too. There are no links to other resources too.

Comment: @Andyaka I just checked the LNA datasheet out of curiosity and at a glance I see nothing that motivates a SAW filter. I think it's a good question, I personally have no idea why the filter is there.

Comment: Or rather, I don't understand why the filter to the left in the schematic is there... the OP seems to have it the other way around. That one is for RF compliance/radiated susceptibility. It should have a pass band of some ~10MHz.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct in that a SAW filter (any filter for that matter, or any device in the more general case) before the first LNA will have an adverse affect on the noise figure of your system.  So in that regard you want the filter after the LNA.

But with the filter after the LNA, there's the possibility that the LNA will go into compression if a large out of band (band meaning your desired frequency range of interest) signal comes in that overloads the LNA.  If this is the situation, then you want a filter before the LNA to attenuate the interferer.

Comment: But why then there is also filter after LNA? To get rid of garmonics?

Comment: @lazba - To reduce out of band signals even more.  There really shouldn't be any harmonics/spurs if the LNA is working properly.  You get those mixing products when the LNA compresses.

Answer (score 3):

The performance of the SAW filters just out of band is good, with -60 dB notches ([datasheet](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/842/tdkc_s_a0001072893_1-2295533.pdf)) but the performance falls off well out of band (-35 dB @ ~400 MHz, -28 dB @ ~2 GHz). A second SAW filter improves the wide-band filtering. Putting it after the LNA keeps the noise figure low.

[image: Graph of SAW filter amplitude response]
Plot from datasheet, page 7